# How does TTS TacTile Code Reader work?

Tags: control

This is the TTS TacTile Code Reader:

https://www.tts-international.com/tactile-code-reader/1010494.html?cgid=Primary-Computing_--_ICT-Bee-Bot_Blue-Bot_--_Pro-Bot

There aren't any connection pins, I guess the tiles are maybe rfid tags.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Comment: i would guess that the device uses multiple RFID readers or one RFID reader with multiple antennas or one RFID reader with one antenna, but multiple tag activation circuits